# What is a pin that has a school symbol on it called as?

Tags: word-request

I have a pin(?) that I have to attach to my shirt every day before going to school. The pin has the school's symbol on it. What is this type of pin called? Does it have a specific name?

[image] [image]

Comment: Maybe it's school badge or button.

Comment: [Lapel pin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapel_pin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In America we would call it a "school pin". I don't know of any schools that have such pins, but at least decades ago school sports teams used to have such pins, and they were called "varsity pins".

The symbol itself might be called a "school logo", but you wouldn't call the pin as a whole that.

Comment: What does *you wouldn't call the pin as a whole that* mean?

Comment: I meant, the symbol by itself might be called a logo. But the whole pin, that is, the symbol, the metal that the symbol is painted on or made from, and the actual pin (the pointy thing itself), that would not be called a "logo". It would be called a "pin".

Answer (score 5):

In English this would be called a School Badge.  American English refers to pins but this would not be correct in the UK